# Como detener el ciclo $.each

Tags: jquery

Saludos, tengo una tabla con `inputs` estos son dinámicos lo que necesito  es validarlos para que no estén vacíos al momento de grabarlos en la `bd`, estos elementos los recorre por medio de un `$.each` en `jquery`, el problema es que el ciclo tiene que acabar en el momento que encuentra un campo vació he intentado con `return false`, `break` e incluso con `return true` pero el ciclo continua y esto evita que pueda hacer el `focus` al elemento vacio, esta estracto de codigo es llamado al hacer click sobre un boton.
**Jquery**

```
if($(".hatrabajado:checked").val()==0){
        $('#historialTrabajo #bodyhisto tr').each(function () {
            var anios = $(this).find(".anios")
            var aniodura = $(this).find(".aniodura")
            var mdura = $(this).find(".mdura")
            if(anios.val()==""){
                anios.addClass("error")
                anios.focus()
                return false;//deberia  salir del ciclo
            }
            if(aniodura.val()==""){
                aniodura.addClass("error")
                aniodura.focus()
                return false;
            }
            if(mdura.val()==""){
                mdura.addClass("error")
                mdura.focus()
                return false;
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué otro código hay arriba y abajo de ese `if`? Para ver si esos no tienen

Comment: @Yikarus solo hay validacion de otros campos

Comment: creo que el problema son las comparaciones. A pesar de que tu comparación es valida puede generar ciertos casos especiales en los que no aplica intenta `if(aniodura.val()==="")`. Con tres **=** en lugar de dos

Comment: @ReneLimon tampoco sigue sin salir pero si entra en el `if` funciona como si el `return false` no existira

Comment: si es que si entra entonces debe haber algo más, hay otro loop aparte?

Comment: @Kevin, ese codigo dispara toda clase de eventos, hay que ver si alguno de esos te está enviando de vuelta al `if($(".hatrabajado:checked")` (no sabemos que eventos llaman al codigo que publicas ahi arriba), yo probaría comentando las lineas con `anios.focus()` y demas focus()

Comment: @ReneLimon no solo existe este en la funcion

Answer (score 1):

Intenta definir una varible fuera del loop, y le retornas la retornas en el if dentro del loop.

Así:

```
if($(".hatrabajado:checked").val()==0){
  var x = true; //==> valor por defecto de return
  $('#historialTrabajo #bodyhisto tr').each(function () {
    var anios = $(this).find(".anios")
    var aniodura = $(this).find(".aniodura")
    var mdura = $(this).find(".mdura")
    if(anios.val()==""){
      anios.addClass("error")
      anios.focus()
      return x = false;//deberia  salir del ciclo
    }
    if(aniodura.val()==""){
      aniodura.addClass("error")
      aniodura.focus()
      return x = false;
    }
    if(mdura.val()==""){
      mdura.addClass("error")
      mdura.focus()
      return x = false;
    }
  })
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Si bien reliza lo esperado pero las validaciones que estan despues no se ejecutan ya que al hacer ''return x` termina la funcion, lo podria validar al final pero no es muy atractivo para el usuario llegar al final del formulario y volver a la mitad nuevamente si se olvido llenar algo